# Anti-Frame Busting code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My frame is redirecting page !! How to stop it ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787608/my-frame-is-redirecting-page-how-to-stop-it)

Is there any code like that ?

Please help..Thanks

Comment: You can look at the links in my answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787608/my-frame-is-redirecting-page-how-to-stop-it/3787630#3787630)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: Luke, use the search. Reach out with your emotions.

Comment: In the link what do you mean by ? http://server-which-responds-with-204.com ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a code that detects if it's in a frame, and if so, change the target location?

```
if (parent.frames.length > 0) parent.location.href = location.href;
```

Comment: No, he is looking for the oposite.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what's being asked.

Comment: Yah i'm looking for an opposite one !!

Comment: Sorry, connected the Anti to the Frame part.